# Mule ESB: checkFrequency not working on IMAP connector?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm using an IMAP connector to connect to an inbox and download messages. I have the checkFrequency parameter set to 30000 (default is 60000). I've tried other values as well. With the exact code below, if I launch the flow it never checks the email on its own. Not even when it first starts and not after 30 seconds. The only way I can get it to work is by simply adding a whitespace to the XML and saving it again. This causes the connector to connect and download the email message. What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:imap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap"
       xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
       xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
       xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.6/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/3.6/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap/3.6/mule-imap.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/3.6/mule-email.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.6/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd" version="EE-3.6.0">

    <imap:connector name="imapConnector" checkFrequency="30000" doc:name="IMAP" /> 

    <expression-transformer name="returnAttachments" doc:name="Expression">
        <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*"/>
    </expression-transformer>

    <file:connector name="fileName" doc:name="File"> 
        <file:expression-filename-parser/> 
    </file:connector>
    <flow name="incoming-orders">
        <imap:inbound-endpoint host="server" port="143" user="user" password="pass" disableTransportTransformer="true" transformer-refs="returnAttachments" doc:name="IMAP" responseTimeout="10000">
        </imap:inbound-endpoint>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]"  >
            <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[key == "test.xml"]]></expression-component>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:\Mule\in" outputPattern="#[key]" doc:name="File" responseTimeout="10000">
                <expression-transformer> 
                    <return-argument expression="payload.inputStream" evaluator="groovy"/> 
                </expression-transformer>
            </file:outbound-endpoint>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to connector definition:

mailboxFolder="INBOX"

Answer (score -1):

You have created a `imapConnector` config which is not used.

Add to your configuration the last attribute

```
<imap:inbound-endpoint host="server" port="143" user="user" password="pass" disableTransportTransformer="true" transformer-refs="returnAttachments" doc:name="IMAP" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="imapConnector">
```

Comment: While that was an obvious problem, it did not fix the issue.  Am I overlooking something else simple?

Comment: Is it possible to set it to 0 so it doesn't repeatedly check and then put it in a Poll Scope?  I really need this working.  I even created a new global connector for IMAP via the GUI and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Actually it was used. When there is only one global connector of a given transport, Mule will use it for that transport's endpoints.